# Find conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that the system has no solutions, one solution and infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ will the following linear system have no solutions, one solution and infinitely many solutions?

$$2x-3y = a$$
$$4x-6y = b$$

It is straightforward to see how the system can have infinitely many solutions or no solutions.

In order for the solution to have infinitely many solutions, we require the y-intercept the of the two lines to be equal. This can be accomplished by observing that

$$4x-6y = b \implies 2x-3y = \frac{b}{2}$$

Therefore, the lines will coincide if $b = 2a$.

Consequently, the two lines are parallel when $b \neq 2a$ (it is clear that the two equations have the same slopes, so that does not need to be checked).

Although I can intuitively see that the two lines will never intersect at a single point, my mathematical justification may be weak, but here is my attempt. Thus my question is whether or not the following reasons for the two lines never intersecting at a single point is valid.

If we subtract $2x-3y=a$ from $4x-6y=b$, we get

$$2x-3y = b-a$$

But I don't see how to conclude from this result that the system does not have a single solution.

Comment: If you subtract *twice* $2x-3y=a$ from $4x-6y=b$ you get $0=b-2a$. So if $b\ne2a$ you have a contradiction and hence no solutions.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, where does the contradiction arise when letting $b\neq 2a$?

Comment: Because by assuming values of $x,y$ exist satisfying the equations you can deduce that  $b=2a$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! The system can never have exactly one solution.

However, your proof is not good. You have provided no evidence that if $b\neq 2a$, then the system has no solution. Sure, you get that $2x-3y=2a-b$, but why would this mean that the system has no solution?

In fact, if you subtract $2x-3y=a$ from $4x-6y=b$, you **do not** get $$2x-3y=2a-b,$$ you get $$2x-36=b-a.$$

Comment: Typo. You mean $3y$ not $36$ in the last line.